# Using Round function in yii2 query

Tags: yii2

I've a query to get mrp*rate from table productbatch upto 2 decimal point.
I've tried the following query `Productbatch::find()->select('mrp, rate, round((mrp*rate),2) as  rateval')->asArray()->one();`

When I use only mrp*rate it gives the result but there's 6 or 7 digits after decimal. Please let me know how can I get the result upto 2 decimal points.

example

If I don't use round and if mrp = 32 and rate = 24.64, the result of `mrp*rate` it gives - 788.47998046875..
If I use Round as shown in the code it doesn't give the result.
What I want is - 788.48.

Productbatch Model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\invoice\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "productbatch".
 *
 * @property integer $itemid
 * @property string $productname
 * @property string $batchno
 * @property string $mfgdate
 * @property string $expdate
 * @property double $mrp
 * @property double $rate
 *
 * @property Productnames $productname0
 */
class Productbatch extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $rateval;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'productbatch';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['batchno'], 'string'],
            [['mfgdate', 'expdate'], 'safe'],
            [['mrp', 'rate'], 'number'],
            [['productname'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
            [['productname'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Productnames::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['productname' => 'productnames_productname']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'itemid' => 'Itemid',
            'productname' => 'Productname',
            'batchno' => 'Batchno',
            'mfgdate' => 'Mfgdate',
            'expdate' => 'Expdate',
            'mrp' => 'Mrp',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductname0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Productnames::className(), ['productnames_productname' => 'productname']);
    }

    public static function getBatchNo($cat_id)
    {
        $out = [];
        $data = Productbatch::find()
                ->where(['productname' => $cat_id])
                ->orDerBy([
                        'expdate'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ])
                ->limit(5)
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
        foreach ($data as $dat) {
            $out[] = ['id' => $dat['batchno'], 'name' => $dat['batchno']];
        }
        return $output = [
            'output' => $out,
            'selected' => ''
        ];
    }
    public static function getItemdetails($cat_id, $subcat_id)
    {
        $out = [];
        $data = Productbatch::find()
                ->where(['productname' => $cat_id])
                ->andWhere(['batchno' => $subcat_id])
                ->orDerBy([
                        'expdate'=>SORT_DESC,
                    ])
                ->limit(5)
                ->asArray()
                ->all();
        foreach ($data as $dat) {
            $out[] = ['id' => $dat['itemid'], 'name' => $dat['itemid']];
        }
        return $output = [
            'output' => $out,
            'selected' => ''
        ];
    }
    // public static function getItemdetails($cat_id, $subcat_id)
    // {
    //     $out = [];
    //     $data = Productbatch::find()
    //             ->where(['productname' => $cat_id])
    //             ->andWhere(['batchno' => $subcat_id])
    //             ->orDerBy([
    //                     'expdate'=>SORT_DESC,
    //                 ])
    //             ->limit(5)
    //             ->asArray()
    //             ->all();
    //     foreach ($data as $dat) {
    //         $out[] = ['id' => $dat['itemid'], 'name' => $dat['itemid']];
    //     }
    //     return $output = [
    //         'output' => $out,
    //         'selected' => ''
    //     ];
    // }
}
```

Controller Action -

```
public function actionGetForItemid($prodname , $batchno)
    {
        $item = Productbatch::find()->joinWith(['productname0'])->joinWith(['productname0', 'productname0.hsncode'])->select('max(itemid) as itemid, expdate, mrp,rate, productname, batchno, round(rate*mrp,2) as rateval')->where(['productname'=>$prodname])->andWhere(['batchno'=>$batchno])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($item);
    }
```

Javascript that is calling the controller action -

```
<?php
/* start getting the itemid */
$script = <<< JS
function getItemID(item) {
    var index  = item.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var batch = product = 0;
    var id = item.attr("id");
    var myString = id.split("-").pop();

    if (myString == "productname") {
        fetch = index.concat("-batchno");
        product = item.val();
        batch = $("#productsales-"+fetch+"").val();
    } else {
       fetch = index.concat("-productname");
       batch = item.val();
       product = $("#productsales-"+fetch+"").val(); 
    }
    $.get('index.php?r=invoice/bills/get-for-itemid',{ prodname : product,batchno : batch}, function(data){
       alert(data);
       var data = $.parseJSON(data);
       var getItemid = data;
       itemID = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-itemid");
       $("#"+itemID+"").val(getItemid["itemid"]);
       expDate = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-expdate");
       $("#"+expDate+"").val(getItemid["expdate"]);
       mRP = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-mrp");
       $("#"+mRP+"").val(getItemid["mrp"]);
       rATE = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-rate");
       $("#"+rATE+"").val(getItemid["rateval"]);

   });
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
/* end getting the itemid */
?>
```

Form fields that is being populated -

```
<?= $form->field($modelsProductsales, "[{$i}]rate")->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class' => 'rate','placeholder' => 'Rate']) ?>
```

Comment: update your question and add  your  ProductBatch Model please

Comment: Use [truncate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) instead of `round()` in query.

Comment: @InsaneSkull, I tried truncate...but it ends up with the same result.-- No output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your Productbatch model has a publica var  rateval

```
class Productbatch extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $rateval
    ...
```

and then you can refer to the rateval content in you views  using

```
   $model->rateval;
```

OR do the fact you have the result not rounded  whet you use `mrp*rate`
a simple solution could be round in javascript

```
  Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

and in your case

```
 $("#"+rATE+"").val( Math.round( getItemid["rateval"]*100)/100  );
```

Comment: Hi scaisEgde.. when I use mrp*rate I get the answer with 6-7 digits after decimal as "rateval" and I can pass it to a textbox. But as soon as I start using "round"... I don't get any reply. I've updated productbatch model as you asked.

Comment: @Tanmay   hey  ..  update you question adding the controller/action where you use the select ..and the related  view  .. please

Comment: Updated Controller action, form, javascript that is calling the controller action

Comment: Update the question and add a data sample received  by your jquery and try using an aler(getItemid["rateval"])  .at the end for the jquery data callback function for check which values  value is transferred..

Comment: I have also update the answer with a suggestion  (if you are not looking for the reason of your problem   but  looking for a fast solution)

Comment: Please tell me how to round the value to 2 decimal point in the following context - rATE = "productsales-".concat(index).concat("-rate");
       $("#"+rATE+"").val(getItemid["rateval"]); This two lines are getting the "rateval" and passing to the form.